# Windows Phone 8.1 MapIcons won't show in MapControl with Aerial MapStyle

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a MapControl to which I add a rather large number of MapIcons objects. I know these are not guaranteed to show but when I switch to Aerial MapStyle, all of them are obscured. Do I do something wrong or is it just the way it is that my MapIcons are deemed less important than the satellite imagery?

XAML children elements are ofcourse still visible but I don't want to use them since they can't stay in place while panning the map and its simply more ugly:(

edit: just to be clear I'm targeting Windows Phone 8.1 runtime